# How to do a Windows Server 2008 R2 activation without internet connection?

Tags: windows-activation

I need to reactivate a server but when I go to activate it, the only option is to go online and the server isn't on the internet.

Is there a way to run the activator to get right to the phone activation?

Anyone know what the .exe is?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/existing-customer/activation-centers); What commands have you tried.  [How you activate Windows Server offline through the phone is well documented.](https://serverfault.com/questions/378355/show-me-other-ways-to-activate-is-disabled)  What step are you stuck on? Since Windows Server is only licensed through VLK, the Microsoft page I provided, is applicable.

Comment: slui 4 just tells me not genuine and says to go online to fix.

Comment: I'm set. I went to change the product key, entered in the same one and it gave me the phone option again.